# How to print the pass message when test passes using TestNG SoftAssertions

Tags: testng

In SoftAssertion, it prints only the fail message when test fail but there is no provision to print the pass message when test passes. I want to print the pass message when SoftAssertion passes.

I have written below wrapper method for AssertEquals as below:
1. SoftAssertion.java ==>>

```
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class SoftAssertion {

    public SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    public SoftAssertion() {
    }

    public void assertAll(){
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

public void assertEquals(String actual, String expected, String failMessage, String passMessage) {
       if (actual.equals(expected)){
               softAssert.assertEquals( actual,  expected,  failMessage);
               Report.testPass(passMessage);
           } else{
               softAssert.assertEquals( actual,  expected,  failMessage);
               Report.testFail(failMessage);
           }
       }
}
```

2. Test class ==>>

```
public class NewSoftAssertTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Report.startReport("New Soft Assert Test",
                "1) Test Soft Assert");

        SoftAssertion softAssert = new SoftAssertion();

        softAssert.assertEquals("A","B","Strings are not equal", "Strings are equal");
        softAssert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello", "Hello is not equal to Hello", "Hello is equal to Hello");

        softAssert.assertAll();

    }
}
```

Above code works perfectly fine. I want to know is this a correct way to log the pass message in TestNG SoftAssert ?

In one of the posts, someone suggested to add the try catch block as below
1. SoftAssertion .java ==>>

```
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class SoftAssertion {

    public SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

    public SoftAssertion() {
    }

    public void assertAll(){
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }

public void assertEquals(String actual, String expected, String failMessage, String passMessage){
       try {
           softAssert.assertEquals(actual, expected, failMessage);
           System.out.println("Assertion passed");
           Report.testPass(passMessage);
       }catch (AssertionError e){
           System.out.println("Assertion failed");
           Report.testFail(failMessage);
           throw e;
       }
   }

}
```

2. Test class ==>>

```
public class NewSoftAssertTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Report.startReport("New Soft Assert Test",
                "1) Test Soft Assert");

        SoftAssertion softAssert = new SoftAssertion();
        softAssert.assertEquals("A","B","Strings are not equal", "Strings are equal");
        softAssert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello", "Hello is not equal to Hello", "Hello is equal to Hello");
        softAssert.assertAll();

    }
}
```

On Console, it correctly shows the assertion failure for A and B but in Report, it passes the step and prints "Strings are equal"

Q1. My question is where is it going wrong ? It should go in the try catch block and log the fail message.

Q2. Which approach is better, the 1st one or the 2nd one using try catch ?

Answer (score 4):

In order to ensure that you get the messages logged for both passed and failed assertions, you can do something like this (I am using the latest released version of TestNG as of today viz., `7.0.0-beta3`):

Build a customized assertion class by extending `org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert` [ You can also take a look at `org.testng.asserts.LoggingAssert` if you want to extend it instead ].

Here's a sample implementation.

```java
import org.testng.asserts.IAssert;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class SimpleLoggingAssert extends SoftAssert {

  @Override
  public void onAssertSuccess(IAssert<?> assertCommand) {
    System.err.println(assertCommand.getMessage() + " <PASSED> ");
  }

  @Override
  public void onAssertFailure(IAssert<?> assertCommand, AssertionError ex) {
    String suffix =
        String.format(
            "Expected [%s] but found [%s]",
            assertCommand.getExpected().toString(), assertCommand.getActual().toString());
    System.err.println(assertCommand.getMessage() + " <FAILED>. " + suffix);
  }
}
```

Here's the test code:

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewSoftAssertTest {

  @Test
  public void myTest() {

    SimpleLoggingAssert softAssert = new SimpleLoggingAssert();

    softAssert.assertEquals("A", "B", "Test1: Ensure strings are equal");
    softAssert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello", "Test2: Ensure strings are equal");

    softAssert.assertAll();
  }
}
```

Here's the execution output

```
Test1: Ensure strings are equal <FAILED>. Expected [B] but found [A]
Test2: Ensure strings are equal <PASSED> 

java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    Test1: Ensure strings are equal expected [B] but found [A]
Expected :B
Actual   :A
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert.assertAll(SoftAssert.java:47)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn55387064.NewSoftAssertTest.myTest(NewSoftAssertTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:570)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:170)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:790)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:763)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:398)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:392)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1146)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:997)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:965)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```